# Zygote: error closing descriptor libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EBADF (Bad file number)

Tags: android, runtime-error

I am getting the error like this to fetch contact from phone. when I click on contact it is showing error like below. I need to display contact like email, address.

> Zygote:  error closing descriptor
>                                                libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
>                                                    at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
>                                                    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75)
>                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.closeServerSocket(ZygoteInit.java:224)
>                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.handleChildProc(ZygoteConnection.java:879)
>                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.runOnce(ZygoteConnection.java:242)
>                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.runSelectLoop(ZygoteInit.java:705)
>                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
>                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

And my code is this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 

data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case (PICK_CONTACT) :
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor contactCursor = getContentResolver().query(contactData, new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID }, null, null, null);
                    String id = null;
                    if (contactCursor.moveToFirst()) {`enter code here`
                        id = contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    }
                    contactCursor.close();
                     phoneNumber = null;
                    Cursor phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER },
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "= ? ",
                            new String[] { id }, null);
                    if (phoneCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    }
                    phoneCursor.close();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

What I need to change in my code